# How explain that no negative is predicted?

Tags: neural-network, keras, confusion-matrix

I have built this model with Keras :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(look_back, trainX.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainX, trainY,validation_split=0.3, epochs=50, batch_size=1000, verbose=1)
```

and the results are surprising... When I do this :

```
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
print(confusion_matrix(trainY, trainPredict.round()))
print(confusion_matrix(testY, testPredict.round()))
```

I respectively get :

```
[[129261      0]
[   172 129138]]
```

and

```
[[10822     0]
[10871     0]]
```

In other words, My training confusion matrix is quite fine while my testing confusion matrix classifies everybody as "positive". What is surprising is that I have quite perfectly balanced instances, both in training and testing set...

Why do I have this ?

Thanks

Comment: why are using round() method??

Comment: @Mitiku I looked at another SO post (can't find it anymore) because I had an error saying you can't compare continuous and binary targets or sth like this

Comment: If so check these are the same for both train and test:- 1. Normalization of data, 2. sampling distribution

Comment: Did you forget any preprocessing step with `trainX` or `testX`? Did you compare training and validatoin losses for overfitting?

Comment: @DanielMöller I don't know think so. I am just a bit fuzzy about the input_shape of data, actually, I used `create_dataset` function mentioned here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/ and with look_back=50. When using early_stopping, I get slightly better results but definitely still bad (last line : 10857 14]

Comment: @DanielMöller any further idea ?